# Kendo notification is not initialized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, notifications, kendo-asp.net-mvc

When I check the kendoNotification after initalization, its appearing undefined. For this reason show() method is not running and notification is not appearing. How to fix this?

```
 <div id="appendto" class="demo-section k-content"></div>  

 <% Html.Kendo().Notification()
   .Name("staticNotification")
   .AppendTo("#appendto");
      %>
```

I am calling the this function on button click event.

```
 function showNotification(text) {
 var staticNotification = $("#staticNotification").data("kendoNotification");

 ////// in here when you check the staticNotification, it is appearing as undefined

 staticNotification.show(kendo.toString(d, 'HH:MM:ss.') + text, "info");
 var container = $(staticNotification.options.appendTo);
 container.scrollTop(container[0].scrollHeight);
 }
```

Comment: Your code looks good, so I think it's not possible to tell the reason with the given snippets, it's probably somewhere else. You could try if the Wrappers are the problem ang generate the Notification in JavaScript ( Example from Demos: http://dojo.telerik.com/asOko ). Other Controls working fine?

Comment: Have you included js "kendo.notification.js" on your page or you have used "kendo.all.min.js"?

Comment: I've checked the kendo js files. All included, but still does not appear. @HemantD

Comment: Other controls working well. Grid, dropdown etc. I ll try on dojo. @thmshd